# Obtain different random() values with generate_series() in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, random

I am trying to generate random data (in volume) and was trying to use PostgreSQL's `random()` function with `generate_series()`, as shown:

```sql
SELECT
  (SELECT random()) AS a,
  (SELECT random()) AS b,
FROM generate_series(1,3);
```

However, **I get the same random values per row**:

```sql
   a   |   b   
-------+-------
 0.124 | 0.443 
 0.124 | 0.443 
 0.124 | 0.443
```

How can this be solved?

Comment: You should not edit the question if it invalidates existing answers. If this is not what you wanted to ask, delete the question and ask a new one.

Comment: Thanks @mustaccio, understood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, quite an annoying "feature". You can fix the problem by stirring in a little of the outer query, in a way that doesn't change the result meaningfully.

```
SELECT
  (SELECT random()+f/1e39) AS a,
  (SELECT random()+f/1e39) AS b
FROM generate_series(1,3) f(f);
```

Comment: can you explain what +f/1e39 is doing with the generated random() number?

Comment: It is just making the subselect formally depend on f from the outer select, so that it gets re-executed for every row.  It does this by adding a microscopically small amount to the random value.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by calling the `random()` function separated from the `generated_series()` call like this:

```sql
    SELECT
    num,
    random() AS rand1,
    random() AS rand2
    FROM generate_series(1,10) AS gs(num)
```

But if you want to do some operations on the random columns, you will have to repeat the random() function call over and over as you can't call rand1 or rand2 directly.

A quick way to fix this is to use a CTE like this:

```sql
WITH rand AS (
    SELECT
    num,
    random() AS rand1,
    random() AS rand2
    FROM generate_series(1,10) AS s(num)
)
SELECT *
FROM rand
;
```